# Totally ordered abelian group with a unique " isolated subgroup"

Tags: real-analysis, abelian-groups, ordered-groups

Let $(G,+,<)$ be a totally ordered abelian group i.e. $(G,+)$ is an abelian group with partial order $<$  such that for every $a,b\in G$, exactly one of $a=b$ or $a<b$ or $b<a$ holds; and for every $a,b,c\in G$, $a<b \implies a+c<b+c$.  Let us call a subgroup $H$ of a totally ordered abelian group $G$ to be isolated if $H\ne G$ and $a\in H, -a<a \implies b\in H, \forall -a<b<a$.

My question is: If $(G,+,<)$ is a totally ordered abelian group with a unique isolated subgroup i.e. the trivial subgroup $\{e\}$ is the only isolated subgroup, then is it true that there is an order preserving isomorphism between $G$ and a subgroup of $(\mathbb R,+)$ with the usual order inherited from real line ?

Comment: Another name for _isolated_ subgroup is _convex_ subgroup.

Comment: @DanielKawai : ok ... so ?

Comment: YES. This is true. I can give a  long but entirely elementary proof.  The idea is to fix some $a_0\in G$ with $a_0>e.$ For $e<x\in G$ and $n\in \Bbb N$ let $f(x,n)\in  \Bbb N$  such that  $nx\leq a_0f(x,n)<(n+1)x.$  Prove that $\psi (x)=\lim_{n\to \infty}n^{-1}f(x,n)$ exists. Let $\psi (y)=-\psi (-y)$ for  $y<e$ and  $\psi (e)=0$. Now prove that $\psi$ is the desired order-preserving  group-isomorphism.  There may be a brief sophisticated proof that I don't know about.

Comment: The long proof  that I mentioned in my previous comment does not require that G is Abelian, provided that we also have $a<b\implies c+a<c+b$.  So we have the result that any fully ordered group with no non-trivial convex sub-groups is Abelian.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Accordingly to this page: "[Order Preserving Isomorphism](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/858975/order-preserving-isomorphism)", it is sufficient to infer the Archimedean property (for every $a,b\in G$, if $a>0$, then there is a $n\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $na\geq b$).

Let $a>0$ be an element of $G$. Let $H=\{x\in G:\exists n\in\mathbb{N}:-na<x<na\}$. Then $-a<0<a$, so $0\in H$. For $x,y\in H$, there are $m,n\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $-ma<x<ma$ and $-na<y<na$, so $-(m+n)a<x-y<(m+n)a$, so $x-y\in H$. Also, for $x,y\in G$, if $0\leq y\leq x$ and $x\in H$ then there is $n\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $0\leq x<na$, so $0\leq y\leq x<na$, so $y\in H$. Therefore, either $H$ is an isolated subgroup (then $H=\{0\}$) or $H=G$, but $-2a<a<2a$, so $a\in H$, so $H\neq\{0\}$, so $H=G$. Therefore, $G$ is Archimedean.